# How to listen to the events of a contract or an address? with web3py

Tags: web3.py

I would like to know if you know how to listen to a contract or an address, because I tried to have all the pending events but I can't filter my address in it, too many txhash recuperate I can't find my txhash in it.

I ran the python code and then sent bnb to another address via metamask but I didn't get the txhash on the python code.

If anyone can help me here is the code:

```
from web3 import Web3
import time

web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider("wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443"))
def main():
        
        filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
        while True:
                try:
                        tx_hashes = web3.eth.getFilterChanges(filter.filter_id)
                        for tx in tx_hashes:
                                tx_receipt = web3.eth.getTransaction(tx)
                                print(tx_receipt)
                except Exception as exception:
                        continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I'm using python

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing events and transactions.

An event is a set of data emited by a transaction **once it is mined**, and only if the tx has been developped to do so.

A transaction is... well, a transaction, not an event.

The consequence is that you cannot listen for event in the pending transaction pool, as those transactions have not been mined yet.

So, to answer:

> I would like to know if you know how to listen to a contract or an
> address

Yes.

- Contract: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html?highlight=event#web3.contract.Contract.events and https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html?highlight=event#advanced-example-fetching-all-token-transfer-events
- Address: not familiar with the python web3, so RTFM.

Comment: i can listen the event like the add of liquidity of the lock of the liquidity ?

Comment: @Zairtay Only if your contract emits an event in these cases.